# Configure unicorn on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, unicorn

I follow these links for configuration

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn
- http://www.neilmiddleton.com/getting-more-from-your-heroku-dynos/

my `config/unicorn.rb`:

```
worker_processes 2
timeout 60
```

With this config, it still gives a timeout error after 30sec.

Answer (score 2):

The Heroku router will timeout all requests at 30 seconds. You cannot reconfigure this.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

It is considered a good idea to set the application level timeouts to a lower value than the hard 30 second limit so that you don't leave dynos processing requests that the router has already timed out.

If you have requests that are regularly taking longer than 30 seconds you may need to push some of the work involved onto a background worker process.

Comment: i have excel file upload and processing function which required sync process to response and its take more then 30 sec so please help me to  change 30 sec limit

Comment: you can't change the limit, it's a hard limit set by Heroku. You will have to split your upload and processing to be able to run in the background with sidekiq, delayed job etc.